# Linking Google voice assistant with a existing live chatbot

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have a chatbot which is live on a website and takes request and gives responses from users in the form of text. I want to integrate Google Voice Assistant in such a manner that the user gives input to the assistant and the assistant asks that from the chatbot and then replies to the user with what the chatbot said. I don't wish to recreate hundreds of intents in order to achieve this with the voice assistant.

I wish to publish this on Google voice assistant instead of creating a mobile app and integrating the voice assistant with it.

Comment: Please provide some specifics. What is the question, what is the challenge, the steps you have tried up to the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Without a great understanding of how your chatbot service is implemented, I can provide high-level steps on adding it to Assistant.

1. Choose to use either [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/) or [Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/). Since you don't need to use Dialogflow for NLU, you can probably just use Actions SDK.
2. Create [a cloud function or some other fulfillment](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/fulfillment) that will handle the `actions.intent.TEXT` intent. Your fulfillment should then make a request to your chatbot service with the user's text. Then you should respond with the result.

```
app.intent('action.intents.TEXT', async (conv) => {
  const chatbotResponse = await queryChatbot(conv.input.raw)
  conv.ask(chatbotResponse.text)
})
```

Comment: Well, this looks stateless... and quite a few conversation apps will have some state. Especially for most back-and-forth conversations.  What fun for someone! And a sign the original question is both too broad and lacking in important details.

Comment: The webhook is designed to be stateless, but state can be carried in the platform between calls in the request.